# LoadScriptsBeforeUI happens after RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I load my external/cdn javascript library with `ScriptManager` (like jquery).

```
ScriptManager.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(name, null));
```

I would like to load them after the UI is loaded

```
ScriptManager.LoadScriptsBeforeUI = false;
```

Then i would like to inject in page some javascript to use them:

```
CurrentPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "scriptName", script, true);
```

The problem is that the script loaded with `RegisterStartupScript` are injected in page before `ScriptManager.Scripts` when `ScriptManager.LoadScriptsBeforeUI = false`.

Do you know a way to load `RegisterStartupScript` after `ScriptManager.Scripts`?

i was wondering if there is a built-in solution in `ScriptManager` class.

Comment: Why would you do it this way? The whole point of `LoadScriptsBeforeUI = false` is so that you don't have to have them loaded before everything else happens. You're either going to have to hook it to load on UI, or you're going to have to use a timer and polling to see if the scripts you need are available.

Comment: you're right but if i load some external script i would like to use them... For example the asp.net javascript for saving scroll position is rendered after ScriptManager.Scripts

Comment: Nothing is included in the ScriptManager to ask it to load scripts on delay, and yet to execute other scripts on page load. It's an either-or proposition, and most people set the flag to true that you're setting to false.

Comment: i don't want a delay but just a different order: first ScriptManager.Scripts then ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: What you want is not supported out of the box. It's possible for you to write it yourself, but you'll have some work involved.

Comment: The reason you want to do it is because your page scripts can then be written in for example jQuery, which is probably one of the things the script manager is loading for you.

You can of course lad jQuery earlier, then load everything else with the script manager, but it's tacky. 

You could otherwise use some standard JS to hook your page scripts onto. But "standard" JS is one of the things it's hard to find without jQuery, in the real world.

So yeah, script manager, sort of a good idea in principle but not great in practice.

Comment: @philw I fully agree with you. In fact I left the script manager long ago and created my own custom loader for scripts.

Comment: One advantage of the script manager is that it automatically "cache busts" IIS when you change constituent scripts.

Comment: @philw i did something similar with my custom scriptmanager using lastwritedate and querystring